# I can't add a subView but through the init method

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview, ios7

I use the "jazzHands" keyframe animation library to help my App finish the introduction view.[jazzHands link](https://github.com/IFTTT/JazzHands)

In the official example, it use a init method to configure the subViews. But I found when I use the viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear or view...,etc methods to configure the subViews, the subView will never add to the superView(self.scrollView), in here, self.scrollView is a subView in the self.view, see the original code below:

```
#import "IFTTTAnimatedScrollViewController.h"

@implementation IFTTTAnimatedScrollViewController

- (id)init
{

    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.animator = [IFTTTAnimator new];
        self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
        self.scrollView.delegate = self;
        [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
    }

    return self;
}
```

But I found that you can add a subView to the self.view and it works! Why??
  help me......

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.....
The reason that I can't add the subView through the viewDidLoad method is that the self.scrollView has already release(nil)